# When using the Release Manager Extension for Tridion 2011 will the Content Porter move releases when porting content between environments?

Tags: 2011, content-porter, release-process

We are looking into the ReleaseManager extension for Tridion 2011.

If we create a release named ABCD_1234 in our Dev environment and use import/export in RM, will we have that same release name in our QA environment after using Content Porter, or will we have to create the release in each environment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ReleaseManager extension is actually only intended to be used to "bundle" a group of Tridion items for a release. The way that it actually works is that it stores all items added to the release in an XML file which is maintained on the filesystem (I've also seen it adapted to be stored in AppData). When you use the ReleaseManager extension to generate the export file, it generates a Content-Porter friendly export XML file which tells Content Porter which files should be exported.

On the subsequent server, you actually just use Content Porter and import the exported zip just as you would any typical release. You can have ReleaseManager installed on this CM as well, however none of your releases will be added to it etc, and would only really serve the purpose of generating releases to be moved into the next environment.

I would recommend you do a bit of reading around Tridion Bundles (introduced in 2013). These are an organizational item similar to Virtual Folders which allow you to group CM items, and can be used similar to ReleaseManager to group a release. You can actually Content Port a bundle as well, so it saves you from having to install a third-party extension, and keeps your releases managed in the Content Managers native interface.

Comment: Bundles are definitely the right tool for the job in many cases, but because of their limitations working between different publications there can be reasons to use release manager, though it is quite outdated now and you might want to update it before using it.

Comment: You could use Release Manager and it's ability to store {the webdav URL / ID of} items from multiple publications and have a app that takes that source and creates the necessary Bundles in the appropriate Publications (although the source of a bundle will show <items> with an ID - they also resolve from WebDAV URLs). These could then be used to Content Port the items and is also a nice way to package them up for sending through workflow and/or Translation etc.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm familiar with Bundles in 2013, but we have not yet upgraded our instances at my current company. Hopefully we will be able to do that soon!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the Tridion community!

The Release Manager extension is quite old. It was excellent back in the day, but today we have Bundles with Tridion.  To directly answer your question, no, you will not have that same release in another environment after Content Porting. All Release Manager does is creates an Export XML file that you can load into Content Porter to pre-select your list of items to export.  When you import the items in the target environment, it is regular content porting outside of the scope of the Release Manager extension.

Also note, the export XML file that RM generates for 2011 is not compatible with Tridion 2013. There are some minor namespace difference that require tweaking the extension. Again, just use Bundles.